# problem with duplicated row saved in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

there is a old mysql problem for me that i couldnt solve and its saving duplicated empty row in some mysql tables

this is my table structure :
 when im trying to query like this :

```
$db->sql_query("INSERT INTO `table_donate`  values (`did`,`name`,`username`,`user_email`,`donate_amount`,`donate_time`,`reveal_info`,`reason`) , (NULL,'".$info[name]."','".$info[username]."','".$info[user_email]."','".$price."','".$ctime."','1','$reason')"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

simply two rows saved after running above query

I wonder how can I fix this problem !?!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO `table_donate` (`did`,`name`,`username`,`user_email`,`donate_amount`,`donate_time`,`reveal_info`,`reason`)
values (NULL,'".$info[name]."','".$info[username]."','".$info[user_email]."','".$price."','".$ctime."','1','$reason')
```

You need to put the table columns, before the `values` sign. Mysql will try to insert everything afterwards.

Alternatively, if you are inserting data into every column, you don't need the column names in the first place.

Comment: If you like an answer, "Accept" it - A perfect way to say thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Anything in parenthesis that comes after `VALUES` will be inserted. You have two `()` lists of items to insert separated by a comma, so two rows are inserted.

The [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) for an `INSERT` statement in MySQL is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

Instead of what you have now, try

```
$db->sql_query("INSERT INTO `table_donate` (`did`,`name`,`username`,`user_email`,`donate_amount`,`donate_time`,`reveal_info`,`reason`) values (NULL,'".$info[name]."','".$info[username]."','".$info[user_email]."','".$price."','".$ctime."','1','$reason')") or die(mysql_error());
```